# Need help rendering ReactJS component - YouTube API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

Just started playing around with ReactJS and YouTube API to automatically pull videos from a playlist. Trying to get the component rendered below but it seems I can't access them "items" list in the state inside my component. See code snippet below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    var thisContext=this;
    $.get("https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?maxResults=4&part=snippet&playlistId={SOME_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={MY_API_KEY}", function (data) {
      thisContext.setState(data);
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Video />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Video extends App {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src={'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.state.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am getting back results on the `$GET` and was able to insert it into `this.state`, but when I try to reference it again inside of the `render()` in `Video` component, I was unable to do so. I'm guessing there's some async/reference issue going on. Any input would be appreciated!

P.S - Bonus question, how would I go about looping over `items[]` to retrieve all the videoID and display them each as a `<Video />` component, or is that not the way to go about looping over the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're using ES6, use arrow function inside the callback to save yourself from setting a `this` reference:

   ```
   componentDidMount = () => {
     $.get("https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?maxResults=4&part=snippet&playlistId={SOME_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={MY_API_KEY}", (data) => {
        this.setState({ items: data });
     });
   }
   ```
2. `render` function is called even before you get your response, and until you get the response `this.state.items` doesn't exist and therefore you get an exception. You can also use `map` to iterate over the items:

   ```
   render() {
       if (!this.state.items || this.state.items.length === 0) {
           return null; // or <div></div>, or a loader, or whatever you want in the meantime
       }

       this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
           return(
             <div>
               <iframe key={ i } width="560" height="315" src={'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.snippet.resourceId.videoId} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
             </div>
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the null check on `this.state.items` worked! Still a bit unfamiliar with how the `Video` component gets rendered. If I returned `null` when the data was not available, how/why does the component load again?

Comment: After every `setState` call or a prop change to the component, the `render` function gets called again. It's not loading again, it's just getting rerendered (meaning constructor/componentWillMount/componentDidMount won't get called, just `render`)

Answer (score 0):

The components not share states, so if you need to pass the 'video data' like props in Video component:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Video video={this.state.data[0]}/>
  </div>
);
```

why this.state.data and not this.state.items? because you are using:

```
this.setState(data) // its equal to this.setState({data: data})
```

And..yes, you should iterate the data for show the videos, something like:

```
// app component
render() {
return (
  { this.state.data( video => (<Video video={video} key={video.etag}/>) ) }
 )
}
```